# TIMESTAMPDIFF - How to use it in PHP/MySQL to calculate difference between date values

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, timestampdiff

[TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506731/get-difference-in-years-between-two-dates)

The link above have helped me how to calculate difference in two dates, however, **I need to do the same on a particular column at run time via MySQL select query inside PHP.**

For example:

Profile table:

- Name
- Gender
- DOB (Date of Birth)

Running following query via MySQL console, gives exactly the needed result:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) AS Age FROM profile;
```

However, I need to complete the following query to get me the same result combined with other conditions on whole set of DOB values:

```
SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE Gender='$gn';
```

I checked Sub-query but that, wont work due to more than one return value.

Comment: Is it `profile` the same table as `Profile`? Then you could just add the calculated column from your first query to the field list of your second query.

Comment: They are same. Could you write that query for me as you referred, It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it's the same table, you could use this query:

```
SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) AS Age
FROM Profile 
WHERE Gender='$gn';
```

Then you'll find an additional field `age` in your result set.

Comment: This query works, however when using Age as part of WHERE clause, MySQL reports Age as Unknown column. #1054 - Unknown column 'Age' in 'where clause'.                                              **I'm trying to achieve the result based on this query...SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) AS Age FROM Profile where gender="Male" AND (Age BETWEEN 20 AND 30);**

Comment: This happens, because this field is named after it was select is done. The time MySQL filters the where-statments, this column haven't been created yet. In this case you'll need to add a having clause instead. This runs after the selection is done. Try this: `SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) AS Age FROM Profile where gender="Male" having (Age BETWEEN 20 AND 30);`

Comment: Works as required.