# SQL equation current your minus other year?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with names and birthday year of doctor. On index page i need to show only doctors who is undex 40 years old. I need to subtract birthday year from current year and show only result under 40 ...

```
SELECT * FROM `doctor` WHERE dateadd(year, `date_birthday`, getdate())
```

i try to cast the date sa datetime to date as year, but everytime it is return NULL

```
SELECT id,CAST((CURDATE()-date_birthday) AS DATE) AS difference FROM doctor
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference in years between two dates in MySQL as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506731/get-difference-in-years-between-two-dates-in-mysql-as-an-integer)

Comment: SELECT id,(CURDATE()-date_birthday) AS difference FROM doctor this is work, but it is convert it to timestamp ... result is 20178533 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify a database and your formatting is inconsistent.  The ANSI standard syntax would be:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM doctor d
WHERE date_birthdate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '40 YEAR';
```

Date/time functions differ by database, so this may not work in your particular database.  Hence, the need for a database tag.

For instance, in MySQL, you would drop the single quotes:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM doctor d
WHERE date_birthdate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 40 YEAR;
```

Comment: @YogeshSharma: It is MySQL. The syntax and the error #1582 give it away

Comment: i use on localhost phpmyadmin - mySQL is 4.5 and PHP version 5.6.33

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `doctor` 
WHERE curdate() > `date_birthday` + interval 40 year
```