# How to calculate age based on date of birth in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

My date of birth format is : **2017-Feb-15**

when I am using the following query, it's not working

```
select (year(current_date)-year(dob)) as age from user
```

or how to current **2017-Feb-15** into **2017-02-15** format

Comment: That's not a very accurate formula for people born on Jan 1st or Dec 31st

Comment: You may find this link usefully: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506731/get-difference-in-years-between-two-dates-in-mysql-as-an-integer'

In short...
Use the datediff(...) mysql function that will give you the difference between to dates.
From the results above use the mysql floor(...) function that will return you the largest integer value that is less than or equal to a number.

Comment: Fix your dob format

Comment: @Tech a good link but the best answer is not the accepted one. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is superior. OP will still need to convert his date format though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, str_to_date(dob, '%Y-%M-%d'), current_date) AS age
from user;
```