# Find Customers who have birthdays in next 7 days in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.8

I need to get list of Customers who have birthdays in next 7 days in laravel. i using following query. that query display passed birthdays also.

```
 $customerslist=Customers::WhereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(date_of_birth) AND DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) + 7 >=  dayofyear(date_of_birth)' )->OrderBy(DB::raw("DAYOFYEAR(date_of_birth)"),'ASC')->get();
```

i use below query listed following but missing some customers
[image]

Missing Customer

[image]

Comment: Haven't you tried to use **whereBetween()** in Laravel?

Comment: Dont use DAYOFYEAR like this. DAYOFYEAR("2018-12-31") is 365 but DAYOFYEAR("2019-01-01") is 1.

Answer (score 5):

I found the raw query with the DAYOFYEAR approach very elegant, because it eliminates all problems with the different years of birth. It will however not  handle leap years very nice.

I found a combination of the BETWEEN and DATE_FORMAT produces the correct results.
It does need a check to handle looking over the years edge.

Here is an example of how to implement this in a scope for your model:

```
public function scopeBirthDayBetween ($query, Carbon $from, Carbon $till)
{
    $fromMonthDay = $from->format('m-d');
    $tillMonthDay = $till->format('m-d');
    if ($fromMonthDay <= $tillMonthDay) {
        //normal search within the one year
        $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$fromMonthDay}' AND '{$tillMonthDay}'");
    } else {
        //we are overlapping a year, search at end and beginning of year
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($fromMonthDay, $tillMonthDay) {
            $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$fromMonthDay}' AND '12-31'")
                ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '{$tillMonthDay}'");
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$users = User::birthDayBetween(Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addWeek())->get()
```

To add ordering on birth *day* rather than birth *date*, some more Raw queries and DATE_FORMAT can help.

```
$users = User::query()
    ->birthDayBetween($from, $till)
    ->orderByRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%m%d')")
    ->orderByRaw("DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%y') desc")
    ->orderBy('first_name')
    ->get();
```

NOTE: When looking over the years edge, the ordering will be off since the users that have their birthday at the beginning of the next year will be ordered first.
I chose to solve that in the front end.

Answer (score 2):

for the immediate solution i have created the raw query

```
// start range 7 days ago
$start = date('z') + 1 - 7;
// end range 7 days from now
$end = date('z') + 1 + 7;
$customerslist = Customers::whereRaw("DAYOFYEAR(birthday) BETWEEN $start AND $end")->get();
```

**EDITED**

So i have Created the **5000** records with the random year and date

> MethodOne  Using Eloquent `filter`

```
$checkRange =   array_map(
        function ($date) {
            return $date->format('Y-m-d');
        },
        \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(now(), now()->addDays(7))->toArray()
    );


    $carbonWay = Customer::get()->filter(function($eachCus) use ( $checkRange){
        return in_array( $eachCus->dob, $checkRange);
    });
```

But if you have **Many Customer** it will heatup the sql server

> Method Two QueryBuilder Way

```
 $eloquentway = Customer::whereDate('dob','>=', now())
                    ->whereDate( 'dob', '<=', now()->addDays(7))
                    ->get();
```

So both results in the Same Results in the same for me

Finaly i have Checked if there the ids are mathes so

```
$idsofCarbon = $carbonWay->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $idsofFilter = $elequentway->pluck('id')->toArray();

    dump(array_diff( $idsofFilter, $idsofCarbon));
    dump(array_diff( $idsofCarbon, $idsofFilter));
```

Both are giving me the `[]` Which means that the result are accurate

For more about date filtering

https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Kindly Comment if any issues

Hope it helps

Comment: I used your query but not listed all customers

Comment: ok i will create some fake data and test it in myside and edit the answer

Comment: DAte Format should be like this format('m-d'), and return should be like this   return in_array( date('m-d', strtotime($eachCus->dob)), $checkRange); Because dob not gonna match with upcoming days due to change of birth year

Answer (score 1):

You could try to read [laravel ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#introduction) article.

Use whereBetween to select the date, and using Carbon date is easier to read.

```
return $this->model
        ->whereBetween('dateOfBirth_Column', [Carbon::today()->toDate(), Carbon::today()->addDays(7)->toDate()])
        ->orderBy('dateOfBirth_Column')
        ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it wont work because it will serach only with the current year

Comment: @Manojkiran.A incorrect. Carbon handles year rollover accurately.

Comment: @BenSholdice If date of birth is listed in the database as for example 1990-06-21, then `Carbon::today()->addDays(7)` **will not** catch this. Even though technically the birthday is tomorrow, it's tomorrow, but 29 years ago. See the issue? Birthdays happen every year, which is why `DAYOFYEAR()` is being used.

Comment: @TimLewis ah yes, you are right. even so, `DAYOFYEAR()` as the original poster used is bad and wont handle the year rollover.

Comment: @BenSholdice That's also correct, but an edge case. For that, you might need to use `IN(365, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` or something.

Comment: it wont work because it will serach only with the current year + 1

Answer (score 1):

As @TimLewis points out in comments, your model has a `date-of-birth` field and you are using it in comparisons with the current date (likely many years after to the date-of-birth).

**php solution:**

for readability, and to handle year rollover issues, you should:

1. use Carbon for your dates & date math
2. find the user's next/upcoming birthday
3. remember that a Y-m-d format usually implies a time of 00:00:00.

```php
$now = Carbon::now();
$customers = Customer::all();

// find next birthday for each customer
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $curyear_bd = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $customer->date_of_birth)->setYear($now->year);
    $now > $curyear_bd->endOfDay() ? $next_bd = $curyear_bd->addYear(1) : $next_bd = $curyear_bd;

    if ($now <= $next_bd->startOfDay() && $next_bd <= Carbon::now()->addDay(7)->endOfDay())
    {
        print "customer $customer->name has birthday coming up\n";
    }
}
```

**MySQL solution**

You could use an SQL query like so:

```sql
select * from customers where
if (
CURDATE() >= date_add(date_of_birth, interval  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())    year), 
             date_add(date_of_birth, interval (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())+1) year), 
             date_add(date_of_birth, interval  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE())    year)
)
between
curdate()
and
date_add(curdate(), interval 7 day);
```

but I'd be wary of timezones (server, client etc). This might warrant its own SO question...

I found the TIMESTAMPDIFF from [Get difference in years between two dates in MySQL as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506731/get-difference-in-years-between-two-dates-in-mysql-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is this

$customerslist = Customers::whereRaw("date_of_birth BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY")->get()

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

On your user model

```php
    use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

    public function scopeBirthdayBetween($query, $dateBegin, $dateEnd)
    {
        $monthBegin = explode('-', $dateBegin)[0];
        $dayBegin = explode('-', $dateBegin)[1];
        $monthEnd = explode('-', $dateEnd)[0];
        $dayEnd = explode('-', $dateEnd)[1];
        $currentYear = date('Y');

        $period = CarbonPeriod::create("$currentYear-$monthBegin-$dayBegin", "$currentYear-$monthEnd-$dayEnd");

        foreach ($period as $key => $date) {
            $queryFn = function($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereMonth("birthday", '=', $date->format('m'))->whereDay("birthday", '=', $date->format('d'));
            };

            if($key === 0) {
                $queryFn($query);
            } else {
                $query->orWhere(function($q) use ($queryFn) {
                    $queryFn($q);
                });
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

Usage:

```php
   User::birthdayBetween('01-30', '02-15')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak on @mallesbixie's original answer sets defaults for the `$from` and `$till` values, defaulting to upcoming birthdays in the next month.

```php
/**
 * @param Builder $builder
 * @param DateTime|null $from
 * @param DateTime|null $till
 * @return Builder
 */
public function scopeUpcomingBirthdays(Builder $builder, DateTime $till = null, DateTime $from = null): Builder
{
    $from = $from ?? today();
    $till = $till ?? today()->addMonth();

    $fromMonthDay = $from->format('m-d');
    $tillMonthDay = $till->format('m-d');
    if ($fromMonthDay <= $tillMonthDay) {
        //normal search within the one year
        return $builder->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$fromMonthDay}' AND '{$tillMonthDay}'");
    }

    //we are overlapping a year, search at end and beginning of year
    return $builder->where(function ($query) use ($fromMonthDay, $tillMonthDay) {
        $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$fromMonthDay}' AND '12-31'")
            ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '{$tillMonthDay}'");
    });
}
```

Usage:

```php
// Get birthdays in the upcoming month
Customers::query()->upcomingBirthdays()->get();

// Get birthdays in the upcoming week
Customers::query()->upcomingBirthdays(today()->addWeek())->get()
```

Answer (score -1):

I added the raw query please check if its working or not and let me know

```
 $customerslist=Customers::WhereRaw(' date_of_birth >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())' )->get();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Using the carbon date

$customerslist= Customers::whereDate('date_of_birth', '<=', Carbon::today()->addDays(7))->get();

Answer (score -1):

I faced this challenge and solved it this way:

```
$next_days = now()->addDays(7);
$customers = Customers::query()->whereMonth('date_of_birth', $next_days->month)->whereDay('date_of_birth',$next_days->day)->get();
```

Comment: That will only give a list of customers where the birthday is on the 7th day from now.
The question needs all the customers who have birthdays in the next 7 days, so you have to do a whereBetween query.